# Pin to Dashboard is not supported in this environment on Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, logging, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-dashboard

When I try to pin a chart through Log Analytics Workspace it says "Pin to Dashboard is not supported in this environment". It was working fine 3 days ago. I have changed no accounts, not subscriptions as everything is the same. It is blurred out and when you hover over it, it gives the error message "Pin to Dashboard is not supported in this environment"

[image]

Comment: This might be due to some changes, and will be fixed later. Could you please try "pin to dashboard" from workbook?

Comment: @IvanYang. Wow, I didn't even knew Workbooks existed. I think I will use that in the meantime the Dashboard is down. Thank you so much for letting me know. Please post your comment as your answer so that I can Mark it as Solved and help help other fellow people of the community.

Comment: Done. Glad that it can help.

Comment: @IvanYang. I talked with the Azure Team and found the answer. I have posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to some changes, and will be fixed later.

At the meantime, you can try to use [Azure Monitor Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview), which can also be used to write query and pin to dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a solution after talking with the Azure team for this problem. It turns out that the answer was in this documentation. When you enable Customer managed key for saved queries, the Pin to dashboard will not be supported and the prerequisites to set CMK was to link a storage account for the query. I had accidentally Linked them while playing with Log Analytics Workspace.

TLDR;
Unlink the Storage Accounts from "Linked storage accounts" Tab in Log Analytics Workspace

[image]

Comment: +1, this worked for me. However, it makes no sense :( i wanted to link a storage account to have these queries and things saved in a visible place, but then this super handy pin-to-dashboard feature is not working :(